# Extract text inside HTML paragraph using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<p>
    <a name="533660373"></a>
    <strong>Title: Point of Sale Threats Proliferate</strong><br />
    <strong>Severity: Normal Severity</strong><br />
    <strong>Published: Thursday, December 04, 2014 20:27</strong><br />
    Several new Point of Sale malware families have emerged recently, to include LusyPOS,..<br />
    <em>Analysis: Emboldened by past success and media attention, threat actors  ..</em>
    <br />
</p>
```

This is a paragraph I want to extact from an HTML page using BeautifulSoup in Python.
I am able to get values inside tags, using the .children & .string methods.
But I am unable to get the text "Several new Point of Sale malware fa..."  which is inside paragraph without any tag. I tried using soup.p.text , .get_text() etc..  but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) with [`text=True`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) to find all text nodes and [`recursive=False`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) to search only among direct children of the parent `p` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<p>
    <a name="533660373"></a>
    <strong>Title: Point of Sale Threats Proliferate</strong><br />
    <strong>Severity: Normal Severity</strong><br />
    <strong>Published: Thursday, December 04, 2014 20:27</strong><br />
    Several new Point of Sale malware families have emerged recently, to include LusyPOS,..<br />
    <em>Analysis: Emboldened by past success and media attention, threat actors  ..</em>
    <br />
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print ''.join(text.strip() for text in soup.p.find_all(text=True, recursive=False))
```

Prints:

```
Several new Point of Sale malware families have emerged recently, to include LusyPOS,..
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-automate-an-excel-sheet-in-python/?ref=feed"

html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for para in htmlParse.find_all("p"):
    print(para.get_text())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.